# Magick++ blur mask

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, blur, magick++

I am trying to convert an ImageMagick command for a blurring mask to Magick++ API.

**ImageMagick**:

```
convert -size 720x478 xc: -sparse-color Barycentric '0,0 black 0,%h white' -function polynomial 4,-4,1 -level 0,50% mask.jpg
```

**Magick++**:

```
Magick::Image mask(Magick::Geometry(720,478), Magick::Color("white"));

double args[6];
args[0] = 0;
args[1] = 0;
args[2] = 0;
args[3] = 0;
args[4] = mask.rows();
args[5] = MaxRGB;

mask.sparseColor(Magick::DefaultChannels, Magick::BarycentricColorInterpolate, 6, args);

args[0] = 4;
args[1] = -4;
args[2] = 1;
args[3] = 0;
args[4] = 0;
args[5] = 0;

mask.quantumOperator(Magick::DefaultChannels, Magick::PolynomialFunction,
    3,args);

parseLevel(image, "0,50%", args); // contains code from mogrify.c for parsing the leveling string

mask.level(args[0], args[1], args[2], ' ');
```

The result I get  is just a white image, whereas the correct mask image should be like this:

[image]

**Can someone please show me my mistake?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I was giving the wrong `ChannelType` in `sparseColor()` function. The `DefaultChannels` enum contains `RGBChannels` with `OpacityChannel` and `IndexChannel`. I had to exclude the latter two from the DefaultChannels enum by bitwise operation. As @ThorngardSO pointed out, the args size also needs to be 10.

**code**:

```
double args[10];

// -sparse-color Barycentric '0,0 black 0,%h white' 

args[0] = 0;           // x = 0
args[1] = 0;           // y = 0
args[2] = 0;           // black (R)
args[3] = 0;           // black (G)
args[4] = 0;           // black (B)
args[5] = 0;           // x = 0
args[6] = mask.rows(); // y = %h
args[7] = MaxRGB;      // white (R)
args[8] = MaxRGB;      // white (G)
args[9] = MaxRGB;      // white (B)

mask.sparseColor((Magick::DefaultChannels & ~OpacityChannel) & ~IndexChannel, Magick::BarycentricColorInterpolate, 10, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mhm, I have no experience with imagemagick, but quickly looking into the docs and at your example, I have a hunch: Maybe the default image type is rgb, and you need three float/double parameters for each color in your sparse-color call. Like that:

```
Magick::Image mask(Magick::Geometry(720,478), Magick::Color("white"));

double args[10];

// -sparse-color Barycentric '0,0 black 0,%h white' 

args[0] = 0;           // x = 0
args[1] = 0;           // y = 0
args[2] = 0;           // black (R)
args[3] = 0;           // black (G)
args[4] = 0;           // black (B)
args[5] = 0;           // x = 0
args[6] = mask.rows(); // y = %h
args[7] = MaxRGB;      // white (R)
args[8] = MaxRGB;      // white (G)
args[9] = MaxRGB;      // white (B)

mask.sparseColor(Magick::DefaultChannels, Magick::BarycentricColorInterpolate, 10, args);
```

Comment: I already tried 12 arguments, x,y and r,g,b,a but I got the same result as before. With 10 arguments it throws exception of invalid arguments.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Then all that's left for me is one final suggestion: break your example up into the smallest pieces to figure out what function is the culprit. IOW: If you comment out quantumOperator() and level(), does the resulting mask look resonable? If yes, add quantumOperator() again. And so on...